# datagridview update to sql database

Tags: sql-server, database, datagridview

I'm having problem with updating my table in sql from my datagridview.

here's how I call the data from sql to my datagrid:

```
        string strsql = "select a.Denomination, a.Value, b.Quantity, b.Amount from [Masterfile].[Denomination] a "+
        "left join [GEARS-POS].[POS].[CashCount] b "+
        "on A.Sequence = B.Sequence order by a.sequence";
        dataGridViewEx1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridViewEx1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dataGridViewEx1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        DataTable dtgt = GearsLibrary.Gears.GetData(strsql, Common.Common.ConnectionString());
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = dtgt;

        dataGridViewEx1.DataSource = bSource;

        dataGridViewEx1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Denomination";
        dataGridViewEx1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Value";
        dataGridViewEx1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
        dataGridViewEx1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Amount";
```

and here's how I update my database using a button click event:

```
        string con = "Data Source=WEBSERVER;Initial Catalog=GEARS-POS;User id=sa;Password=123456";
        string strsql = "select a.Denomination, a.Value, b.Quantity, b.Amount from [Masterfile].[Denomination] a " +
        "left join [GEARS-POS].[POS].[CashCount] b " +
        "on A.Sequence = B.Sequence order by a.sequence";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, con);
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Update(dt);
```

Whenever I click the update button, nothing happens. It won't update my table or anything. :/

Comment: You are using a select statement in the Update event !!

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you use a Datatable called "dtgt" as Datasource, and when you want to update data you use another Datatable Called Dt, So you should make an update to the same dataSource.
Instead to write:

```cs
da.Update(dt);

//You must write:
da.Update(dtgt);
```